# The use of "one" as a pronoun

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

When using "one" as a pronoun, should subsequent pronouns also be "one" or variations thereof? If not, which pronoun should be used?

Example:

> When describing oneself in a resume, one must not understate one's abilities.

This sounds horribly clunky to me. Is there another way of wording this?

Comment: Reads ok to me. Depends what you are used to. Probably a difference between British and US usage. In speech “you” is more natural.

Comment: Yes, subsequent pronouns should be _one_ (if you choose to go with that style).

Comment: There are many ways to avoid the clunky use of the same word (in this case, "one") repeatedly. For instance: "In a résumé it is best to avoid understating one's abilities."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's advice directed at a reader, it would sound cleaner with "you":

*When describing yourself in a resume, don't understate your abilities.*

If you insist on the remote-sounding "oneself", it could be

*When describing oneself in a resume, abilities should not be understated.*

Comment: The question was whether one should use *one*, and 'if not, which pronoun should be used?' This is not an answer to **that** specific question; it, rather, offers ways of avoiding it. The answer to the question is in Ms. Bunting's comment.

Comment: @jsw29  From the question itself :"Is there another way of wording this?".